# Understanding the purpose of returning and passing custom Objects in OOP

Tags: php, c++, swift, class, oop

First of all let me tell you that programming is my hobby (love programming) and even though I have taken some programming classes in college (C++) and have created some small programs in C++(QT), Objective-C, PHP and now Swift, I have never had the need to heavily use custom objects other than create instances, call some functions/methods from those objects or inherit from one to the other, all pretty simple stuff. The one thing that has been bothering me and that I think is the heart of the OOP world is understanding the concept of creating and using custom objects. I know this question is something I should have asked long time ago, shame on me.

Can someone be so kind and create a quick and simple example of how and what functionality is usually involved when creating custom objects?

Here I'm using Swift but this could be in any other language:

```
// custom object
class ClassA{

    // what functionality could fit here
}

class ClassB{

     init(customObject:ClassA){
         // when would you pass a custom object to this class?
     {

        func returnCustomObjec()->ClassA{
        // when would you return a custom object?
    }
        func passCustomObject(customObjec:ClassA){
        // when would you pass a custom object?
    }
}
```

FYI - I know when to return or pass, Stings, Ints, Doubles, etc. but I want to see when would make sense to create functions that return or accept custom objects in a real program.

Comment: This seems like a really broad topic that you are better off learning from a book or searching the Internet for topics. Covering the advantages of Objects has a very broad scope. QT is full of objects, so if you are familiar with it, then you should be able to ascertain why and how objects are used. Without some context, we can't tell you how you'd use objects in your example.

Comment: Do you have any specific book that you could recommend that uses custom objects? All of the books I have read are more of a how-to reference.

Comment: One of the usages is Dependency Injection.

Comment: Search for Dependency Injection

Comment: Ok, I will look into books that use that concept, I believe the Laravel framework uses Dependency Injection a lot. Thanks

Comment: @fs_tigre Just about any C++ book should have a section on Object Oriented Programming and what problems it solves.

Comment: You might want to look into what OOP is all about.  You are not really asking the "right" question to get the answer you desire.

Comment: Sorry for being obtuse, but... I don't exactly understand what is meant by custom objects. An anonymous object, created on the fly? A non built-in type?

Comment: I don't understand how you've taken "some" (i.e. > 1) C++ classes in college without having created a multitude of your own classes. *Any* book on C++ is full of them.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - A non built-in type. I have built a lot of custom objects and used inheritance a lot but I have never passed around these types to other classes.

Comment: I see you have already accepted an answer, but for lots of examples I suggest you read the book "Design Patterns" (http://preview.tinyurl.com/phb8ctv). If the book costs too much for you, the check it out from the library, but it's one of those books that every programmer should own IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my, there is a lot, lot of cases that does this. I just made some object that deal with uniform shaders in opengl. See my simplified code. There is a lot of object involved here:

```
Shader ShaderManager::load(Camera* camera, Entity* entity) {
    Shader shader;

    shader.addUniform("transform", make_unique<TransformUniform>(camera));
    shader.addUniform("color", make_unique<Vec4Uniform>(entity->getColor()));

    return shader;
}
```

And even color is an object, a very simple struct, but still an object. I rarely deal with primitives, but again some of my object act as primitive (I'm in C++, dynamic allocation is a choice)

Comment: Guillaume Racicot - I think you example is close to what I'm trying to understand. But there are a few things that I don't fully understand. In your example you have a method that returns a type `Shader` but it is declared as "void" shouldn't this be `Shader ShaderManager::load(Camera* camera, Entity* entity){//...}`?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, must be a typo. Thank for the correction.

Comment: Guillaume Racicot - I'm getting closer, now let me see if I understand this concept. Is the method `addUniform` implemented in class `Shader` right? If my assumption is right, I got it now..

Comment: Exactly. `addUniform` takes a `unique_ptr<Uniform>` as parameter and store it in a list. structs and classes are just a way to put a concept  and a way to do things into one construct. So `Shader` encapsulate all the logic behind what's a shader, and need to deal with uniforms. Object are a way to group data and logic with a name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example, I just needed an example to get around this concept. I will keep reading more about it

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the most basic use of custom objects is return types of functions. Lets say I want to write a function that returns an `int` a `double` and a `string` then I could do this by passing references:

```
void foo(int& a,double& b,string& c);
```

However, in this way it is not so clear that these parameters are only for return values. And also now the caller has to take care to declare (and maybe initialize) these 3 variables and has to give them reasonable names. If the return type is lightweight and copying is not a problem, this can be done like this:

```
struct foo_returnType {
    int a;
    double b;
    string c;
}

foo_returnType foo();
```

Now there is no confusion whether its return values or parameters and more importantly if the function returns those 3 parameters, it is very likely that they logically belong together and this should be reflected in the code. I can give them a reasonable name (maybe something better than `foo_returnType`) and for convenience I can provide some more nice features for this new type (e.g. overloading ostreams << operator to print the type on the screen with some additional meaningful information on the meaning of the 3 parameters).

Comment: I think the main point is "it is very likely that they logically belong together". Objects are meant to encapsulate instances of properties that apply to a single "object". A cat has whiskers, fur, purrs, and pounces. A car has 4 wheels, an engine, can drive in a given direction in forward or reverse.

Comment: @crush I remember the story of cars that have wheels and an engine from school, but I always wonder where this thing with the cat with fur, purrs and that stuff is coming from

Comment: The cat example is usually used to illustrate polymorphism/inheritance. You start with a base Animal or Mammal class, then specialize it into a cat. The idea is to illustrate that objects encapsulate properties and actions that define said object.

Comment: Well, I do get the concept of inheritance, but for some reason I don't fully understand when to pass or return a custom object. I will read more about the Dependency Injection concept.

Comment: @fs_tigre Mislead by stupid teachers with all their cars and animals I thought for very long time that inheritance is the main point of having classes. For some reason the point where I started to really like C++ coincided with me realizing that inheritance can be nice but its definitely not the main advantage of having custom types/classes.

Comment: Exactly, I feel like I'm missing the real purpose of using custom classes.

Comment: @fs_tigre I gave you an example where there is no inheritance or dependency injection or whatsoever, just a plain custom class. I really think this is super useful and I use it for return types on an every day basis. What is it that you dont understand on this example?

Comment: @tobi303 Your example returns an int, a double and a string, I have no problem with that, I do that all the time. My issue is that I don't know when to pass or return custom objects (other than int, floats etc). As some other have suggested I think I need to read more about advance OOP. Thanks

Comment: @fs_tigre My example is not returning an int, a double and a string, but it returns an object that encapsulates an int, a double and a string. That may seem a minor difference but actually it is a major one when you consider readability, maintainability and convenience for the user of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I have a php backgound. I messed around a bit with c++ and java, but this answer is in a php perspective.

In php, custom objects are the objects which **actually do things** (in java there are a lot of libraries if I understand correctly, one might be able to do a *lot* without any custom object). That is, objects representing your business entities, such as an invoice or a sale item, or representing your application, such as a http response object, or a template parser object.

Passing and returning custom objects ensures that your methods will have a predictable behavior, that is, not calling non-existing methods on your objects, being sure that if you type-hint an interface in a method, any object that implements the `sumable` interface *will* be able to be sumed (for example).

**The purpose of passing and returning cutom objects is to ensure of an application's behavior**